# Stackoverflow's style login with facebook account

Tags: facebook, authentication

Hello I'm trying to make option for users to login to my site with their facebook accounts.
As far as I read in facebook api I have found only [login with pop-up window](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login), but I don't like It...
I'd like to make it like here on stackoverflow
1. user click on "login" image ot button
**2. whole window goes to FB page and ask user for perm**
3. get back user to my page...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use:

http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

You can do something along the lines of:

```
    $facebook = new facebook();
    $fbSession = $facebook ->getSession();

    //IF user is logged in
    if ($fbSession)
    {
        $_SESSION['fbsession'] = json_encode($fbSession);
    }
     else
    {
        header('Location: '.$facebook->getLoginUrl());
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm talking about. Thank you !

Comment: so which means when we open the login page of of web app, then on load, we hsould write this code. And when we forward the user to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize this userl, it will automatically pick those values. Just like stackoverflow did. They redirects user to this url using javascript on click of facebook button. Please correct me if I am wrong.