# Facebook login in site?

Tags: facebook, authentication, autologin

I have a question about this feature. I want to add a button like Facebook login. When someone clicks it I want to retrieve his email and maybe his name or surname. Generally I want to provide this service instead of filling such form manually. Any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stackoverflow's style login with facebook account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123639/stackoverflows-style-login-with-facebook-account)

Comment: Yes, a suggestion: go read this, try it, then ask if there's anything unclear: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ There are even tutorial examples in that page.

Comment: try the [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) and THEN rephrase your question with the problems faced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Implementing Facebook login / single sign-on (part 1)](http://blog.mixu.net/2010/12/27/implementing-facebook-login-single-sign-on-part-1/)
- [Implementing Facebook login (part 2)](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/03/implementing-facebook-login-part-2/)
- [Implementing Facebook login (part 3)](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/09/implementing-facebook-login-part-3/)
- [Google search : facebook login for developers](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=facebook%20login%20for%20developers)

Comment: How About adding some snippets from the links you posted?

Comment: The user clearly hasn't even gone to the Facebook developer page as this is all very well documented in there, there is no one snippet that can do it, the user is asking for a TOTAL solution, not just a code review or fix.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login - Read about the SDK, you will need to make an attempt for yourself before you ask others to do your work for you.